# Do I need to include details about a side trip to another country on my Schengen application form?

Tags: visas, schengen, legal

I will be applying for my tourist visa at the Germany embassy as my main destination is Germany however I would like to take a side trip to Italy for maybe 3 days.

Do I need to add Italy as a second destination on my application form? And so will I have to show proof of hotel accommodation, etc.? I will stay with a friend while in Germany…

Comment: A convincing Schengen application will show every night of the visit accounted for; so yes, you should try to meet the requirements by doing that.

Comment: To follow up on @GayotFow's comment: suppose you chose not to disclose the trip to Italy in the application.  How would the official processing the application know about it, after all?  Then suppose in your interview that the official asks you a question that causes you to mention something about Italy.  That could put your application in serious jeopardy.  Or suppose they decide to call your friend who will be putting you up in Germany, to compare stories.  Better to tell the truth up front, so you don't have to worry about what you say in the interview.

Comment: @phoog, that's good for an answer also.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You do not want to lie. As @phoog said and as I would like to add on, you should mention everything. Lying can have serious consequences and you or your friend might accidentally let something slip. It could be minor, "Italy is such a nice place", or major "Have you visited [landmark]? I went there yesterday."

As @Blackbird57 said, lying may also negatively affect future visa applications.

Comment: Having a visa application refused for omitting information can also negatively affect future visa applications, and not just in the EU

Comment: @Blackbird57 Good point, I'll add it in.